# What is the Lagrange Multiplier value?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Is the Lagrange Multiplier typically the magnitude of the gradient of the objective function in the direction of the constraint function?

Let $f(x,y,z)$ be an objective function and $g(x,y,z)=0$ be a constraint.

$\nabla f $ is the direction of maximum growth of $f$.

$\frac{\nabla f \cdot \nabla g}{\nabla g \cdot \nabla g} \nabla g$ is the vector projection of the gradient of $f$ along the gradient of $g$.

So $\nabla f - \frac{\nabla f \cdot \nabla g}{\nabla g \cdot \nabla g} \nabla g$ is the direction of greatest change of $f$ that leaves $g$ unchanged.

Instead of $df=\nabla f \cdot \vec{ds}=0$ to get an extremum, use $\nabla f - \frac{\nabla f \cdot \nabla g}{\nabla g \cdot \nabla g} \nabla g=0$ to take the constraint into account.

But this is the same criterion for lagrange multipliers, $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$. So I'm wondering is it usually the case that $\lambda =\frac{\nabla f \cdot \nabla g}{\nabla g \cdot \nabla g}$?

I've always thought of $\lambda$ as a constant in the past.

Comment: Another perspective is that the multiplier is the derivative of the constrained extreme value (max or min) as a function of the constraint value. In economics terms, if you're maximizing utility subject to a fixed budget, the multiplier is the marginal utility of money.

Comment: Under suitable qualifications, the Lagrange multiplier is the rate of change of the optimal cost with respect to a change in the corresponding constraint (that is $g(x,y,z) = c$ for some variable $c$, nominally $0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed. Nice observation. From $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$, taking the scalar product with $\nabla g$ follows the equation for $\lambda$ which you wrote.